# Convert postgres timestamp with timezone between timezones

Tags: postgresql, datetime, timezone

I have data stored in a timestamp with timezone column (timestamptz) in UTC.

I want to query in a different timezone (Australia/Sydney +10) but retain the timezone

```
SELECT 
    '2022-05-04 14:00:01.546+00'::timestamp AT time zone 'UTC',
    timezone('Australia/Sydney', '2022-05-04 14:00:01.546+00'::timestamp AT time zone 'UTC')
;
```

This returns:

"2022-05-04 14:00:01.546+00" timestamp with time zone

"2022-05-05 00:00:01.546"    timestamp without time zone

What I want is:

"2022-05-05 00:00:01.546+10" timestamp with time zone

i.e. convert from +00 to +10 and retain the time zone. I keep finding examples that convert to local time without the timezone info. I'm trying to map to a pyarrow.Table and want to infer the correct type `timestamp[ns, tz=Australia/Sydney]` rather than `timestamp[ns, tz=UTC]`

Edit: To make it clearer I've tried the following:

```
select
    ts,
    timezone('Australia/Sydney', ts),
    ts at time zone 'Australia/Sydney'
from timeseries
limit 1
```

[image]

Comment: I think all you need is `the_column at time zone 'Australia/Sydney'`

Comment: That gives me the same as `timezone('Australia/Sydney', the_column)` - a `timestamp without timezone` of value "2022-05-05 00:00:01.546". At least when I run it in pgAdmin

Comment: That will most certainly return a `timestamp WITH time zone`

Comment: That what I was expecting - but I've pasted in the output from pdAdmin and its a localised naive timezone from what I can see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way PostgreSQL works, the only way to get the output `2022-05-05 00:00:01.546+10` is to set the `timezone` parameter to a time zone with that UTC offset:

```
SET timezone = 'Australia/Sydney';
```

Comment: Ah right, yes that works. I'm not sure I can send multiple statements using `connectorx` but thanks anyway. I think I might use UTC and convert the pyarrow.Table column on the client.